# Find non trivial entries in $S = \{A = [a_{ij}]_{n×n} : AD = DA\}$ where $A$ is any square matrix of order $n$ and $D$ is diagonal matrix.

Tags: matrices

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ be a square matrix of order $n$ and let $D = \operatorname{diag}[\underbrace{a, a, \ldots, a}_{p\ \text{times}},\underbrace{ b, b, \ldots, b}_{q\ \text{times}},\underbrace{ c, c, ..., c}_{r\ \text{times}}]$ then number of non trivial entries in the set $S = \{A = [a_{ij}]_{n\times n} : AD = DA\}$

I have seen somewhere that number of non trivial entries  in $S$ are $p^2+q^2+r^2$ but I have no idea how to calculate this.

Comment: To get you started, think of block diagonal matrices, having a $p \times p$ block, followed by a $q \times q$ block and then an $r \times r$ block diaogonally, and zeros everywhere else. Do such matrices commute with $D$?

Comment: Please more elaborate the structure of block matrix.

Comment: see this article for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix.